# StopWatch for users C#

Tags: c#, object-oriented, reinventing-the-wheel

I have tried to create a stopwatch and I have done but I don't know how to improve it, and I want the user control the stopwatch whether it (Start) or (Stop), I'll be thankful if you tell me what I can do to improve my code.

**StopWatch.cs**

```
public class StopWatch
{
    private DateTime _startTime;
    private DateTime _stopTime;
    private bool _timeRunning = false;

    public void Start(DateTime Start)
    {
        if (!_timeRunning)
        {
            _startTime = Start;
            _timeRunning = true;
        }
        else
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Stopwatch is already running!");
    }

    public void Stop(DateTime Stop)
    {
        if (_timeRunning)
        {
            _stopTime = Stop;
            _timeRunning = false;
        }
    }

    public TimeSpan GeTime()
    {
        var duration = _stopTime - _startTime;
        return duration;
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var stopwatch = new StopWatch();

        stopwatch.Start(DateTime.Now);

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }

        stopwatch.Stop(DateTime.Now);

        Console.WriteLine(@"Time Elapsed : {0:hh\:mm\:ss}", stopwatch.GeTime());
    }
```

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using the `Stopwatch` provided by the framework?

Comment: I just want to practice in a way that how class and methods work

Comment: @EslamAli To make it possible to interact with your stopwatch, the time counting needs to happen asynchronously in a separate thread.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ How can I make separate thread, Do you mean take the input from the user and turn into millisecond?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: what do you mean? Are you referring to those `Thread.Sleep` calls? Those aren't part of the stopwatch, they're just test code.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet No, I mean that interacting with a stop watch from arbitrary user input would require asynchronous code (e.g. updating a time display).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: all right, but that doesn't seem to be the purpose of this class. This is just for measuring how long something took.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet "I want the user control the stopwatch whether it (Start) or (Stop)"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally I wouldn't recommend creating a class with almost exactly the same name as a framework class (your `StopWatch` vs the existing `Stopwatch`), but you mentioned that this is an exercise, so let's ignore that for now.

- The basic approach here seems fine: `Start` stores the start time, `Stop` stores the end time, and `GetTime` returns the difference. But there's a bug: `GetTime` does not work correctly if the stopwatch is still running. In that case, instead of looking at the (incorrect) stop time, it should look at the current time.
- Why do `Start` and `Stop` take a `DateTime` as argument? That's something that the stopwatch itself should be doing. If, for some reason, you really must allow calling code to pass in their own times, then your stopwatch class should probably verify that the stop time is not earlier than the start time.
- Why does `Start` throw an exception if the stopwatch is already running? Is that really something that should not be allowed? If so, why is it allowed to call `Stop` on a stopped stopwatch? I see no real reason for this inconsistency.
- If starting a running stopwatch is not allowed, why can't a caller determine whether a stopwatch is running? A read-only `IsRunning` property that returns `_timeRunning` would be useful.
- As you know, there's already a `Stopwatch` class in `System.Diagnostics`, so I would encourage you to [look at its source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Stopwatch.cs,ceb0ba9cc88de82e). You'll see several differences. One in particular is that it remembers the total elapsed time across multiple start/stop calls. Related to that are the `Reset` and `Restart` methods, and there's a convenient static `StartNew` method. It also uses lower-level methods for more accurate timing.